# Why will cursor not fade when my computer tries to suspend?

Tags: suspend, 20.04

When my computer tries to go fade the screen to black when inactive, the cursor does not fade and the computer immediately wakes up.  I have tried changing the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` file to have everything disabled, but to no effect.  I tried creating an `rc.local`, but no help.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04.